# "In toto" versus "in total"

Tags: word-choice, adverbs, latin

Are the phrases "in total" and "in toto" interchangeable, or is "in total" a corruption of "in toto"?

Comment: Steve Lukather used to be *in Toto*, but since they broke up he's been doing mostly session work. (I couldn't resist.)

Comment: _In total_ is in no sense a "corruption" of _in toto_. They are phrases from the same root, which have taken different paths to get here. _In toto_ is direct from Latin, and usable in English only as a phrase, not in its parts; _total_ is an independent word that comes through French, from Latin _totalis_, an adjectival form from _totus_, "whole".

Answer (score 10, accepted):

*In toto* has taken on the more general sense of "taken as a whole" in general English usage. *In total* means something closer to the original meaning of the Latin version, though there's little doubt in my mind that its use is influenced by the presence of *in toto*, since we already had the phrase *in all* to describe a final sum.

Answer (score 6):

They're interchangeable.  "In toto" is the Latin for "in total", so more appropriate to the sort of formal context where randomly lapsing into Latin is least likely to result in accusations of being [lexiphanic](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/lexiphanic).

Though of course, [quidquid Latine dictum sit, altum sonatur](http://translate.google.com/#la|en|quidquid%20Latine%20dictum%20sit,%20altum%20sonatur).

Comment: Whilst the last phrase is certainly true, I am always struck that using the word *lexiphanic* is self-fulfilling. ;-)

Comment: @Orbling: Yes, it's why I love it so. ;)

Comment: Yes, it should be used more.  I think I will accuse my boss of lexiphanicism the next time he starts trying to speak techno-babble at clients.

Comment: @Orbling: you probably mean than _lexiphanic_ is self-referential.

Comment: @ogerard: Self-fulfilling too, if you use it, you become it.